# Correcting estimate of covariance/correlation with overlapping/autocorrelated data

Tags: references, autocorrelation, covariance, overlapping-data

I'm wondering how to correct for the presence of autocorrelation/heteroscedasticity in estimating sample covariance matrices from data.

I know there have been some questions on this before:

- [Covariance estimation of overlapping time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154979/covariance-estimation-of-overlapping-time-series)
- [Correlation and coefficient with overlapping data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130018/correlation-and-coefficient-with-overlapping-data)

However, these answers seem to be relevant when estimating regressions $y = Xb + a$. In my case I have no such regression - I only want to estimate the sample covariance $\sigma(X)$. However I know that my data $X$ is autocorrelated because I'm using overlapping data. Is there any literature on this?

Comment: If you're not in a regression scenario then why is autocorrelation an issue?

Comment: @Digio, why would you think so? A naive estimate of the covariance under overlapping data will be biased, so that is a legitimate problem to be concerned about.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question but I can't think of ways of correcting autocorrelation without using a time series model.